# Jquery and Html storage not adding correctly

Tags: jquery, html

I have a small program that you click a button to add one coin and than if you refresh it will keep your previous coins.

Only issue is that when you refresh it(run the fiddle) it shows your last coins but when you click              `Add another coin` It starts counting at Zero again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var currentCoins = 0;
 $('#playerBank').html("Coins:" + localStorage.getItem('coins'));

 $('#click').click(function () {
    currentCoins = currentCoins+=1;

   localStorage.setItem('coins', currentCoins);

    var newCoins = localStorage.getItem('coins');
    $('#playerBank').html("Coins:" + newCoins);
    console.log("User:12920 Now has: " + newCoins + " In there bank!");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7h3s26ey/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
currentCoins = currentCoins+=1;
```

to:

```
currentCoins = +localStorage.getItem('coins') + 1;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7h3s26ey/10/)**

You set `currentCoins = 0` every time the page loads when you really want to read from localStorage.

Comment: What does the `+` do before `localStorage.getItem()`?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining that. The plus tells JS to interpret the string from localStorage as a number. Similar to parseInt(). See Unary plus (+) at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators